# Method for destroying activity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, public-activity, acts-as-votable

I am using the acts_as_votable and public_activity gems, and want to remove activities when posts are 'unliked'. The public_activity docs specify using `dependent: :destroy`... however, there is no model for 'likes', and so there is nothing to destroy. The docs don't seem to include a method for manually removing activity on other actions.

For anyone familiar with the public_activity gem, have you ever run into this issue and how did you solve it?

Comment: Please write the title of your question for humans and use tagging to add keywords.

Comment: Oops, sorry about that - thanks!